Cannot install mysqlclient on MacOS 14
I need to install mysqlclient for python, so I use command pip install mysqlclient,
but I get following:
In file included from src/MySQLdb/_mysql.c:29:
      /opt/homebrew/Cellar/mysql/8.3.0_1/include/mysql/mysql.h:46:10: fatal error: 'sys/types.h' file not found
      #include <sys/types.h>
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~

After I set environment variable,
export set CFLAGS="-isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/"

it fails with different error:
error: unable to create target: 'No available targets are compatible with triple "x86_64-apple-macosx10.9.0"'
      1 error generated.

And when I set variable following way:
export set CFLAGS="-isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/ -mmacosx-version-min=14.4"

I get similar error.
Has anyone run into this issue?

you will need the connctor not the client

Is Docker an option?

Instead of usage of mysqlclient, it indeed might be better option to use mysql-connector:
pip install mysql-connector-python

I needed it for Django, so I replaced Django database engine with mysql.connector.django.
Yet enother option is discussed here. Also workable.
